# Service now announcement 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: console, saas, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, service-not-available

In service now I'm getting this error on the console for each request can anyone tell me what exactly the problem is and how can I get rid of this...

here is the error:

> https://ven01234.service-now.com/api/now/sp/announcement 500 (Internal
> Server Error)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get rid of this console error - go to Plugins at your SN instance and search for Service Portal Announcements plugin (ID - com.glide.service-portal.announcements). After you activate it - the console error is no longer being thrown.

[image]

Comment: This does not the problem in my case. The plugin is activated and exactly as in the picture but still - the error comes again. :/

Answer (score 1):

The fix that worked for me is found on [this link](https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0860971)

> Resolution
> There is an empty value on display style field for the announcement "ISC:Invalid Run As User".
>
> Open the announcement "ISC:Invalid Run As User" which has a valid to  date is either today or after.
>
> The value for the display style filed is seems to be empty in the form but if you check in the xml it has a value of sys id "7f8fe758c31023002ff2554d81d3ae99" which does not exist.
>
> ...
>
> Change this value and add a value from the search; Then save it; Then delete the value again; Save it again; With that you are removing the invalid reference for "<display_style/>" from the xml. Basically you assign a valid value to Display style field, save it, then remove it, save it and the invalid reference is gone.
> Do this for every "ISC:Invalid Run As User" from the list

Basically the steps to fix the error are these:

1. In the service now (backend) - search for announcements - (Service Portal -> Announcements)
2. Search "ISC:Invalid Run As User" in the column "Name"
3. For every record with the name "ISC:Invalid Run As User" do the next step.

[image]

Note how there is a (i) button next to the empty "Display style" field - meaning there is some reference which in our case is invalid and should be deleted from the xml field - "display_style"

The value for the display style filed is seems to be empty in the form but if you check in the xml it has a value of sys id "7f8fe758c31023002ff2554d81d3ae99" which does not exist.

4. Assign a valid value to "Display style" field (in my case 'Normal'), save it, then remove it, save it and the invalid reference is gone. **Do this for every "ISC:Invalid Run As User" from the list in "Announcements"**

Enjoy!

This fixed the error for me.

Answer (score -1):

This error means that your page doesnt work correctly!
when you go to this page do you see error?

Comment: Yes this console error is coming all over the `portal` (all pages)